# IBM MQI: How to implement message segmentation?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm looking for the "correct" way to implement the message segmentation with MQI.

Primary I need to implement the receiving part, but for testing purpose I also want to implement the sending side.

Maybe I'm to dumb to search correctly, but I haven't found much documentation/examples for this topic.
Best explanation so far:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=33458 (i think this is taken from an ibm developer pdf). It's a general explanation with some pseudo code/no java code.

There are so much flags and possibilites for the mqget call and also the simple access to the mqueue.

Code examples I tried will follow, but maybe someone has some experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

Does this sample help? Here I am allowing the queue manager to segment a message if the message length exceeds maximum message length of queue.

```
          MQQueue mqQueue = queueManager.accessQueue("SEG.Q", CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_PASS_ALL_CONTEXT);

          /**
           * Put a message and allow it to segmented if the length of each
           * the message we are putting exceeds the maximum message length.
           * For test purpose, the maximum message length has been set to
           * 500 bytes on queue. 
           */
          MQMessage msgPut = new MQMessage();
          byte [] largeBuffer = new byte[2000];

          for(int i = 0; i< 2000; i++){
              largeBuffer[i] = 'A';
          }

          msgPut.write(largeBuffer);
          msgPut.messageFlags = MQConstants.MQMF_SEGMENTATION_ALLOWED;
          MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
          mqQueue.put(msgPut,pmo);            
          System.out.println("Message put successful");

          /* Now receive the same message but as a complete message
           * instead of segments
           */
         MQMessage msgGet = new MQMessage();
         MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
         gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG;
         mqQueue.get(msgGet,gmo);
```

Comment: I think I tried nearly the same and it fails:
The put operation fails with "message to long" on queue or chanel level. I don't know about the get, because I get no message into the queue.

Comment: Could you specify your thoughts because of the access queue parameters?
{CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_PASS_ALL_CONTEXT}

I only have set the MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT option

Comment: MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT is fine

Comment: I used both input and output because I do put and get in the same application

Comment: K. But as i said, the code for put doesn't work. I tried it and I get a MQJE001: Beendigungscode 2, Ursache 2010(sry, german language) error. which means "message to long". I have tested this with a 60 MB File.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576586/websphere-mq-6-message-segmentation-option-ignored-in-put

"A message that is larger than the channel's max message length will not be placed on the queue regardless of whether the message can be segmented or the max message sizes allowed by the queue and queue manager."